# Flash content returened by ASP.Net application is not displayed on IE 9

Tags: asp.net, flash

I have ASP.Net application which has ASHX handler to return content type of "application/x-shockwave-flash" for certain request.

When I'm trying test the application on my local server, the IE doesn't display anything but when I tried it with Chrome it worked perfectly.

The Security Settings for the Local Intenet Zone are the default settions and the Advance Settings are also the default.

I have Adobe Flash Player 11 ActiveX

This is my code:

```
HttpResponse response = context.Response;

response.Clear(); 

context.Response.ContentType = "application/x-shockwave-flash";

byte[] buffer = BlobStorageService.DownloadByteArray("MyContainer","8_L001_1.swf");

System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(buffer);
ms.WriteTo(response.OutputStream);

ms.Close();
response.End();
```

What could be the problem?